Linear Regression with gaussian mixture prior
In linear regression, we assume that the output variable is Normally distributed, i.e., $p(y|\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{w}) = N (y | \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x}, \sigma^2_y)$. I want to assign a mixture of Gaussian prior to each element of $\mathbf{w}$ such that $p(w_j | z_j=k) = N(w_j | \mu_k, \sigma_k^2)$ where prior $p(z_j=k) = \pi_k$ for $k=1:K$. My goal is to infer $K$ center points $\{\mu_k\}$, clustering the elements of $\mathbf{w}$ that maximizes the likelihood of ouptut variable given a set of $ \mathbf{x}_i, y_i$ pairs. I will then use those cluster centers as quantization levels. I tried to use EM algorithm to do this but couldn't derive the posterior distrubitions. Is there any similar model in the literature that I can refer to? Any help is appreciated.

I suggest to look at Spike and slab prior which is basically a mixture gaussian prior over parameters to induce shrinkage.However some softwares do not support categorical priors.

Is $K$ known or should it be estimated as well?  And, roughly, what are the dimensions of $w$ and the sample size?

What are you hoping to achieve with a mixture prior? Did you maybe mean a mixture likelihood?

@jbowman, $K$ is known. We can think of it as the number of clusters. For now, we can assume that the sample size is much larger than the dimension of $\mathbf{w}$.

@Durden, I am trying to achieve learning quantized weights, so thought the mixture prior could do that.  After fitting the model, I will replace elements of $\mathbf{w}$ with learned quantization levels $\mu_k$ depending on the posterior if that makes sense.
